# Nginx Redirect entire domain to specific URL

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I am attempting to redirect an entire vanity domain to a specific URL for our main domain at the NGINX level. I have tried all of the following, but in all cases the domain will redirect not to the specific page but to the top level domain.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;

    server_name vanityurl.com www.vanityurl.com;
    return 301 https://myrealurl.com/internal/landingpage/;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;

    server_name vanityurl.com www.vanityurl.com;
    location / {
         return 301 https://myrealurl.com/internal/landingpage/;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;

    server_name vanityurl.com www.vanityurl.com;

    rewrite ^/$ https://myrealurl.com/internal/landingpage/ permanent;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://myrealurl.com/internal/landingpage/ permanent;
}
```

I've tried each of these individually and all did the same thing, redirect me to https://myrealurl.com/ dropping the internal/landingpage/.

Comment: You need to check the response headers (using curl or your browser's toolbox) to understand what is happening.

Comment: I have checked in Chrome, Firefox and with curl. I get back a 

Request Status Code:301 Moved Permanently
Location:https://myrealurl.com/

when I want (expect) a

Request Status Code:301 Moved Permanently
Location:https://myrealurl.com/internal/landingpage/

Comment: Test the `nginx` configuration with `nginx -T`.

Comment: @RichardSmith I literally just did this, probably as you were replying, and there is an odd character in the file that is breaking the rule. I just cleared it and I am getting the correct behavior. Looks like PEBKAC. Thanks!